# Given a conventional 6t sram in cadence, how do I measure the power and delay parameters?

Tags: sram

I am required to simulate and analyze the 6t SRAM using Cadence
Virtuoso software. However, I am confused about how the measurements will be taken. For calculating SNM, I would have to consider the hold, read and write operations separately, with different circuits. But how do I measure total power and delay?

Comment: Whoever gave you this assignment should define what exactly they mean by "total power" and "delay".

Comment: Sorry, it's leakage power, read access delay and write access delay